# Create blocks in pandas for deduplication

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a data de-duplication problem and would like to compare different rows that have some fields in common.

For Example,

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
         'Name': ['Sam', 'John', 'Christian', 'Sam', 'Christian'],
         'Phone': [900, 800, 700, 600, 500],
         'City': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df
```

---

```
City    Name        Phone
a       Sam         900
b       John        800
c       Christian   700
d       Sam         600
e       Christian   500
```

In this dataframe, rows (1,4) and (3,5) have same name and are my potential duplicates. How do I make pairs of rows for which the 'Name' matches?

Expected output

```
Name1      City1 Phone1 Name2      City2 Phone2
Sam        a     900    Sam        d     600
Christian  c     700    Christian  e     500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it helps

```
pd.concat([df1[1].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix(i+1) for i,df1 in enumerate(df[df.duplicated('Name',keep=False)].groupby('Name',as_index=False))],axis=1)
Out[218]: 
  City1      Name1  Phone1 City2 Name2  Phone2
0     c  Christian     700     a   Sam     900
1     e  Christian     500     d   Sam     600
```

***EDIT: This seems like what you want***

```
df1=df[df.duplicated('Name',keep=False)]
df1['G']=df1.groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1)
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True).drop('G',1).add_suffix(i) for i,df1 in df1.groupby('G')],axis=1)


Out[308]: 
  City1      Name1  Phone1 City2      Name2  Phone2
0     a        Sam     900     d        Sam     600
1     c  Christian     700     e  Christian     500
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with some sort of aggregation function. One option is

```
def aggregate(rows):
    result = {}
    for index, dict_ in enumerate(rows.apply(dict, 1)):
        result.update({'{}{}'.format(key, index + 1): value for key, value in dict_.iteritems()})
    return pd.Series(result)

df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).groupby('Name').apply(aggregate).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
  City1 City2      Name1      Name2  Phone1  Phone2
0     c     e  Christian  Christian     700     500
1     a     d        Sam        Sam     900     600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
duplicates = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df.itertuples():

    possible_dups = df[(df.Name == row.Name) & (df.index > row.Index)]
    duplicates = duplicates.append(pd.merge(possible_dups,df.loc[[row.Index],:],on='Name'))

duplicates

City_x  Name        Phone_x City_y  Phone_y
0   d   Sam         600     a       900
0   e   Christian   500     c       700
```

My inefficient solution - Loop through the rows, find the rows of duplicates (where index is greater and name is same), merge the row, and then append it to a df that was created.